# Laravel Eloquent BelongsTo() issue with echoing results

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

EDIT : I solved it. I'm leaving it here as a reference, I hope it helps someone in the future.

I'm trying to echo out a comment's owner like below, but it gives an error.

> Trying to get property of non-object

```
$comments = ThingComment::where('thing_id', $id)>orderBy('comment_date', 'desc')->get();
```

blade template

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    @foreach($comment->thingCommentOwner as $owner)
        {{$owner->user_name}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I have three models : `User`, `Thing` and `ThingComment` Thing probably isn't important, so I didn't include it.

My tables are : `users` and `thing_comment`

`user_id` and `thing_id` are foreign keys in the thing_comment table. I should be able to access the users table columns through the thing_comment table, that's what I'm trying to achieve here.

Models are below.

ThingComment.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class ThingComment extends Model {

    protected $table = 'thing_comment';
    protected $primaryKey = 'comment_id';

    protected $fillable = ['comment', 'comment_date', 'upvotes', 'downvotes', 'user_id', 'thing_id', 'parent_comment_id'];

    public function thingCommentOwner() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User','user_id');
    }

    public function commentThing() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Thing','thing_id');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They need to be used like below. thingCommentOwner allows us to JUMP to the users table, which is cool.

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    {{$comment->comment}}
    {{$comment->thingCommentOwner->name}}
    {{$comment->thingCommentOwner->user_image}}
    <p></p>
@endforeach
```